# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference , react redux and when use connect

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

> when i want to configuration react redux and set connect in my Routes
>   component i get this err ,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';


import SendNumber from './src/container/SendNumber';
import EnterCode from './src/container/EnterCode';
import Home from './src/container/Home';
import Profile from './src/container/Profile';
import ResultItemsPage from './src/container/ResultItemsPage'
import Details from './src/container/Details'




//back button
const backButton = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Actions.pop()}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 20, marginLeft: 20 }}
    >
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Image
                source={require('./Assets/Images/left-arrow.png')}
                style={{ width: 30, height: 20 }}
            />
            {/*
                <Icon name='ios-arrow-round-back' style={{ color: '#fff' }} />
            */}
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const backButtonDetail = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
            backgroundColor: '#33333320',
            padding: 10,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            borderRadius: 30,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            top: 10,
            start: 10,

        }} onPress={() => Actions.pop()} >
        <Image style={{
            width: 30,
            resizeMode: 'contain'
        }}
            source={require('./Assets/Images/left-arrow-white.png')} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
)



class Routes extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            login: false
        }

    }
    _storeData = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('login', 'true');
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
        }
    };
    _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
            alert(value)
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
        }
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this._storeData();
        this._retrieveData();


    }

    render() {
        return (

            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" >

                    <Scene key="SendNumber"
                        component={SendNumber}
                        title="Send Number"
                        hideNavBar={true}
                        initial={true}


                    />
                    <Scene key="EnterCode" component={EnterCode}
                        title=""
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'transparent' }}
                        renderBackButton={() => backButton()}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.login_style_bar}
                        sceneStyle={styles.login_scene_style}

                    />

                    <Scene key="Home"
                        component={Home}
                        title="home"
                        hideNavBar={true}

                    />

                    <Scene key="Profile" component={Profile}
                        title=""
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'transparent' }}
                        renderBackButton={() => backButton()}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.login_style_bar}
                        sceneStyle={styles.login_scene_style}
                    />

                    <Scene key="ResultItemsPage" component={ResultItemsPage}
                        title=""
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'transparent' }}
                        renderBackButton={() => backButton()}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.login_style_bar}
                        sceneStyle={styles.login_scene_style}
                        onRight={() => alert('right')}
                        // rightButtonImage={require('./Assets/Images/bell.png')}
                        renderRightButton={() => (
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notification_box}
                                onPress={() => alert('توجهات')}>
                                <ImageBackground
                                    style={styles.bell}
                                    source={require('./Assets/Images/bell.png')}
                                >
                                    <View style={styles.notification} >
                                        <Text style={styles.notification_text} >3</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </ImageBackground>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                    />

                    <Scene key="Details" component={Details}
                        title=""
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
                        renderBackButton={() => backButtonDetail()}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.login_style_bar_detail}
                        sceneStyle={styles.login_scene_style}

                    />

                </Scene>
            </Router >
        )

    }
}
















const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        status: state.number.loginStatus
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

const styles = ({
    login_style_bar: {
        backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
        shadowColor: "#f7f7f7",
        elevation: 0,
        height: 50,
    },
    login_style_bar_detail: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        shadowColor: "#f7f7f7",
        elevation: 0,
        height: 50,
    },
    bell: {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    notification: {
        width: 14,
        height: 14,
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: '#B22850',
        start: 10,
        top: -10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    notification_text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 9,
        fontFamily: 'ISFMedium',
    },

```
notification_box: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    right: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
bell: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
notification: {
    width: 14,
    height: 14,
    borderRadius: 7,
    backgroundColor: '#B22850',
    start: 10,
    top: -10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
notification_text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 9,
    fontFamily: 'ISFMedium',
},
```

})